# Phalanger PhpNetCore cannot be found

Tags: php, iis, phalanger

I am trying to setup Phalanger to run on a remote IIS using the

http://www.php-compiler.net/?p=354

guide. Because I am trying to override the server configuration from the web.config, I have the following line added in:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="PhalangerHandler" path="*.php" verb="*" type="PHP.Core.RequestHandler, PhpNetCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a8e8c4c76728c71" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

which makes the ISS server recognize the .php extention. The issue I have is that it cannot find the "PhpNetCore". I am guessing this is happening because it is going off the root location of the server which I don't need. I have the dll inside the

```
 /bin
```

folder. Any idea on how to make the server look in the correct directory? I have tried to add bin/ to the filename but it does not work. According to their documentation, I need to add

```
    <paths>
        <set name="DynamicWrappers" value=".\Dynamic"/>
        <set name="Libraries" value=".\Bin"/>
        <set name="ExtWrappers" value=".\Bin"/>
        <set name="ExtNatives" value=".\Bin\Extensions"/>
    </paths>
```

to the  which I have done so. However it is still not recognizing properly. Any idea on what is going on? Any help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the similar question at http://support.devsense.com/viewtopic.php?t=748

Try to ensure the Application Pool is set to ASP.NET 4.0 integrated (not 2.0, not classic) and the virtual directory is configured as IIS application.